# Asymptotic moments of the first-passage time

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, variance, means

I am reading a paper (Predictability of escape for a stochastic saddle-node bifurcation: When rare events are typical, Herbert, Bouchet, 2017 Physical Review E), which is related to Kramers escape rate of a Langevin system.

I couldn't understand how to determine an asymptotic behavior of the moments of the first-passage time when the noise, $\epsilon$, goes to infinity, where the PDF of the first-passage time is

$P(t) = \sqrt{-t}/\pi * \exp [ -4(-t)^{3/2}/(3\epsilon) ] * \exp[-\epsilon/(2\pi)*\exp[-4(-t)^{3/2}/(3\epsilon)]]$

and it is derived to have n-th moments of

$E[t^n] = k (-1)^n/(2\pi)*(3\epsilon  \ln(\epsilon)/4)^{2n/3}$

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: This looks like the Eyring-Kramer law. I know of a very nice introductory paper on the subject... alas in French (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02441580/document).

Comment: Yes, it is about the escape time distribution related to Kramers rate. Thanks for the suggestion. If any other in English, will be more than welcome too! :)